# Need help in unbricking soft bricked LG G2 LS980

Tags: unbricking, htc-desire-z, lg

I recently purchased **LG G2 LS980** (locked on Sprint network in USA) in India and unlocked it to work in India. The build number of the software that came with phone was **LS980ZV7**.

The phone kept downloading OTA updates (which I could never stop) and I kept installing them. The software version updated from ZV7 to ZV8 to ZVA. After ZVA, the phone downloaded ZVA to ZVC update (611 MB) several times, installed but never updated the software version. In every update, the phone rebooted, optimized apps and booted normally.

One day, I installed TWRP (Team Win Recovery Project) on my phone. The phone again downloaded an ZVA to ZVC OTA update . I went on to install the OTA update. The phone rebooted into TWRP and never booted back into normal mode since then.

In an effort to restore the phone, I did what ever possible to restore the phone. I even did the hard reset of the phone. But the phone still boots into TWRP.

Now, in a way, the phone is "soft bricked". And the only option (I may be wrong) seems to flash the phone with a custom ROM.

Any help please.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flash with custom ROM.

Important:

1. Backup IMEI and WiFi MAC address before flashing (nvram folder).
2. Use a laptop with fully charged battery, same for device.
3. You may need try different ROMs, don't worry if the first one did not work.

Comment: I am afraid but I suppose I no longer have access to the file system of the phone.

Comment: If you don't check format option, that folder would not be overwritten by new ROM. Most flash tools are aware about this and support the option.

Answer (score 0):

I have installed the custom ROM using the instructions as mentioned in the link below:

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2432476

Thanks